# ExpressJS problem with rendering subdomain

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web-deployment

I am writing store and i have a problem with rendering.

I want to have subdomain /category and it's working just find for route like tis

`const CategoryOne = ((req, res) =>{
  res.render('shop/category');
});
router.get('/category', CategoryOne);`

This is working perfect, but when i go on subdomain category/shoes i want to be redirect on /category with parametr shoes

```
const Category = ((req, res) =>{
  const categoryPass = req.params.category;
  res.render('shop/category', {
    category: categoryPass 
  });
});
router.get('/category/:category', Category);
```

and it's not working, should i redirect? When i do it

```
res.redirect('/category')
```

Then i dont have category parametr

EDIT:
What i have done so far:

```
const CategoryOne = ((req, res) =>{
const passedCategory = req.session.categorypassed;
req.session.categorypassed = undefined;
console.log(passedCategory);
Product.find((err, response) => {
res.render('shop/category', {
  title: 'Test', products: response, category: passedCategory
});
});

});

const Category = ((req, res) =>{
  req.session.categorypassed = req.params.category;
  res.redirect('/category');
});
```

The problem is, when i refresh page i dont have this paramets, is there any way to save it?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? Are you saying the handler is never called or just that the URL doesn't update? This could be a number of issues, please elaborate. Also FWIW `category/shoes` _isnt_ a sub domain...

Comment: @James I want after going to /category/shoes to redirect on /category with parametr shoes
By "doesn't work" i mean i'm on /category/shoes and all my images, css and js file from public can't load - error 404

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you're asking for isn't clear.  First, as @James said '/category/shoes' isn't a subdomain, it's a path.  A subdomain would be part of the domain name, for example api.example.com is a subdomain of example.com.  Second, if what you're saying is that when you try and render your 'shop/category' view, you don't correctly load all the associated assets called in the HTML page (e.g. stuff in the public folder), then you need to provide more info about your folder structure and how you've configured the rest of your app's middleware and routing.

Comment: @Paul ok, but still it doesnt matter what my site shows in /category/shoes
when user goes on /category/shoes i want to redirect him on /category and pass parameter shoes

Comment: Sounds like a pretty horrible user experience.  Good luck!

Comment: @Sebqu why do you want to redirect back to `/category` when the user lands on `/category/shoes`? I think there's maybe a language barrier here as that surely isn't correct, do you mean you just want to render the same HTML template you do for `/category`?

Comment: @Paul Why horrible user experience? I'm not here to ask if you like idea, i just have an idea and i want to do it

Comment: @James as i said i want to redirect back to /category with shoes paremeters, no render template. I have edited code, so if you can help me i will be thankful

Comment: use exact path naming for your assets.  you can keep your assets in a central public directory and refer to them as `/assets/images/logo.png` instead of `assets/images/logo.png` for instance

Comment: @Deryck That you so much, i have decided to render not redirect and its working, thank you so much!

Comment: glad to hear it.  In case others end up in this predicament I'll put it as an actual answer here for easy reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to handle this is to use a central public directory for your assets and request them with an **absolute path**, such as `/assets/images/logo.png`, instead of a **relative path**, such as `assets/images/logo.png`.

You can read more about relative and absolute paths [here](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths)